# SVN merging from trunk to branch

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am a newbie when it comes to trunk/branch so my question my be stupid.

I am using the Eclipse plugin of Subversion.
At the moment I am experimenting to see exactly how to work.

I created a branch and then went back to my trunk and made a small change to one of the objects (was version 1 and is now version2) . I committed it.

I went back to my branch where the object is still version 1 and performed a merge command.
What I would have expected to have seen would be that that object is now at version 2 in my branch.
Instead I get it as a modified version 1.

Surely it should just "copy" over the new one since I haven't made any changes on my branch.

I even selected the option of "Resolve Conflict By Using Incoming Version" but I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to be. Merging applies the changes betwee two revisions of one branch (the trunk-rev-1 and trunk-rev2, in your case) to the working copy of another branch. Once your working copy is updated, you can test if the merge doesn't break everything (compilation is OK, unit tests pass, etc.), apply other changes manually if needed, and then commit the working copy. This will create a new revision in the repository.

Files don't have any revision in SVN. The whole repository goes from one revision to another.

I suggest you read the free [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html), which explains evrything very clearly.

Comment: When I look at the files in the SVN viewer in Eclipse it does have a revision number next to it. Why can't I just point to the same one? By having it copy the changes and me having to commit it puts me back into the situation where we have 2 versions of the same file - even though they are identical in contents.

Comment: The version it shows is the number of the last revision of the repository where the file mas modified (or created). Why can't you just point to the same one: because that's not how SVN works.

Comment: But when I originally create the branch I do point at the same file.

Comment: Yes, so what? If you want to change how SVN works, propose your changes to the Apache foundation. But that's how it works currently, and there's no way around it.